# Estimating uncertainties in parameters from minimization of an expression

Tags: optimization, measurement-error, error-propagation

I was curious if they are anything in the literature about estimating or propagating uncertainties when the desired result is from the minimization of an expression. I have several books on uncertainty propagation, but they do not talk about such problems. I suspect in the statistics literature, this problem might have a specific name I am not aware of. I do not think this is a regression, so the methods for those problems do not apply.

I was thinking of changing the parameter's value until the quantity being minimized changes within a desired tolerance. This tolerance would be estimated from the error propagation of the function being minimized because the parameters are not derived from any measured quantities. The measured quantities and the unknowns are both used in the expression being minimized.